# Firebase fetch Data Dictionary

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I don't know how to fetch data in `Swift 4` Firebase. I need to fetch data dictionary in the dictionary.

This is my data in Firebase:

[image: This My Data in firebase Please click this link to show Image]

I want to fetch data in "Episodes".

Comment: Did you try anything already? If so, update your question to show where you got stuck. If not, I'd recommend starting with the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists

Comment: Thanks for your help . I just want Pull Data in “Episodes” to my Project

Comment: Ok - where's the code you've tried to use? The documentation covers that in the the Read Data section.

Answer (score 1):

I would first create a NSObject class. To make retrieving easier.

```
class EpShow: NSObject {

private var Ep1:String!
private var Ep2:String!

init(Ep1:String, Ep2:String) {
    self.Ep1 = Ep1
    self.Ep2 = Ep2
}

public func getEp1() -> String{
    return Ep1
}

public func getEp2() -> String{
    return Ep2
}

public func setEp1(one:String){
    Ep1 = one
}

public func setEp2(two:String){
    Ep2 = two
}

convenience override init() {
    self.init(Ep1: " ", Ep2: " ")
}
```

To add to firebase

```
var ref:DatabaseRefernce!
var counter:Int = 1
ref = Database.database().reference().child("Featured")

    ref.childByAutoId().child("Episodes").setValue([
        "Ep1": String(counter),
        "Ep2": String(counter + 1)
    ])

    counter += 1
```

and to get the data in the nested child

```
private var ep = [EpShow]()
ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        for idAutoChild in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
            for episodesChild in idAutoChild.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                let e = episodesChild.value as! [String:AnyObject]
                let epOne = e["Ep1"] as! String
                let epTwo = e["Ep2"] as! String

                let show = EpShow(Ep1: epOne, Ep2: epTwo)
                print("Ep1: \(show.getEp1()) \n Ep2: \(show.getEp2())")
                 self.ep.append(show)

            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks Adam for your help ❤️❤️